# Getting different file size by changing method of specifying file path

Tags: java

I am getting different sizes of files by using different methods of passing the complete file path.

Method 1: in this method I used File(File parent, String child) method.

```
package udacity;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
public class fileandmethods {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File name= new File("E:/");
    File filename= new File(name,"go.txt");

    String alpha= filename.getName();
    String alpha1= filename.getParent();
    System.out.println(name.length());
    System.out.println(alpha);
    System.out.println(alpha1);

}}
```

output:

```
4096
go.txt
E:\
```

Method 2: in this I passed the abstract path of the file by using method File (String pathname).

```
package udacity;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
public class fileandmethods {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    File filename= new File("E:/go.txt");
    File name= new File("E:/go.txt");
    String alpha= filename.getName();
    String alpha1= filename.getParent();
    System.out.println(name.length());
    System.out.println(alpha);
    System.out.println(alpha1);

}}
```

output2:

```
4
go.txt
E:\
```

So can anybody please tell me the reason for this. The actual size is 4.

Comment: First example: `File name= new File("E:/");`, second - `File name= new File("E:/go.txt");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that when you created a file this way:

```
File name= new File("E:/");
```

you wrapped a `File` around the root directory in the `E:` drive.  However, when you did this:

```
File name= new File("E:/go.txt");
```

you wrapped a `File` around a 4 byte file.

From the Javadoc for [`File#length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length()):

> Returns the length of the file denoted by this abstract pathname. The return value is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory.

So it would seem that the 4 byte size you see for the file is accurate, but the size for `E:/` is "unspecified," meaning we cannot rely on this value.

Comment: but size of the e directory is not 4096 byte so how is it possible.

Comment: @GURMEETSINGH `File::length` doesn't return the size of the directory. It returns... something else.

Comment: i was also having same doubt as i read somewhere that to find size of the file you should use longLength() method but eclipse was showing error in it and self fixed it by replacing it with length().